# Incredibly slow desktop composition (WPR trace included)

Tags: windows-10, performance

I've had a certain problem in recent months, I've worked around or tolerated it, but I can't stand it anymory. (I think it's gotten worse, but that's likely just bias on my part.)

The jist is - Desktop composition for me is unbelievably slow - any time I try to open an explorer window, or the save-as dialog to save a picture from my browser or any number of other things, the window takes an absurdly long time to paint - like on the order of 2-4 seconds. Meanwhile everything else on the system is practically frozen.

The problem gets worse over time.

It's almost okay on a fresh boot - that is, windows launch and respond fast enough to be usable, but I can still see UI elements pop-in one by one - e.g. address bar, ribbon, sidebar.

After a while it gets unbearable - it's a slow decline in performance, in a few hours it's annoying, after a day or so without a restart it's almost unusable.

I took a [WPR trace](https://send.firefox.com/download/ac884328bd79029e/#kWf6cHGAuxmKnBI1MwjHjg) with CPU, GPU, Disk, Network and Desktop composition.
(The link expires after a week. [Backup link](https://martixy.dmn-design.com/z/MARTIXY-PC-NEW.03-02-2020.00-25-52.7z) from my own computer.)

My machine is Asrock Z390 Phantom Gaming 6, i9-9900K, 64 GB DDR4 3000MHz, GTX 1070, 165Hz GSync monitor on DP + 60 Hz monitor on DVI.

I also have a Corsair K70 keyboard. It comes with a program called iCue, which controls its lightning and other functions. Normally explorer.exe is the most egregious offender. If I start that explorer becomes practically unusable - with a response/paint time on the order of 10 seconds. And it starts affecting other windows. Another user in the Corsair forums reported similar problems with the same motherboard family - it makes me think IT is somehow at fault. (trace is without it running because I don't allow it to run, because I would like to actually use computer)

But wait, IT GETS WEIRDER - I wanted to compress the trace, so I can share it over the internet - and during the compression period, when the zipping program was hitting my CPU and memory hard things got snappy again - like after a restart. As soon as zipping finishes we're back to the painfully slow window drawing.
(This gives me an idea - download BOINC and stress my CPU so system remains responsive. Ok. Tested that - as long as I keep my CPU somewhere above 30% or so - like 4-5 cores, it remains responsive.)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns and set Options menu to Hide Microsoft Entries then go to Explorer tab and untick those you don't know.

Comment: Ah, you underestimate me. Already have autoruns. Did as you asked. Only thing I don't recognize is `AirShellExtContextMenuHandler.AirContextMenu`. There is also some bs related to optane (from intel RST I guess), which I recognize, but definitely don't need. The rest is stuff I explicitly use frequently - 7z context menu, HardLink Shell Extension, classic start menu.

Comment: Uncheck them all and restart ALL Explorer.exe processes and see if it fixes it. If it does reenable half. If it is an Explorer addin then rebooting is overkill just terminating and restarting Explorer should be enough. Explorer.exe is the program that supplies the start menu, taskbar, and a folder window called the desktop.

Comment: @Mark Disabling all of them does nothing to help. Isn't composition part of dwm anyway?

Comment: You can try stopping dwm.exe on the details tab in Task Manager, it will restart automatically, to test your theory.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. The only thing that makes the computer responsive is >30% cpu usage. Or maybe >x amount of cores loaded? At least with that workaround I can benchmark when a potential solution is working. Nothing I tried so far is.

Comment: Then look at the other tabs in Autoruns. When your computer is slow type in a command prompt `tasklist` to copy to clipboard `tasklist | Clip`.

Comment: @Mark There is a reason I took a performance trace - exactly so we don't have to play these guessing games and pass-the-logfile. I've been trying to figure out how you read these things. I can spot the hiccups - when explorer just chokes, but I can't figure out why yet.

Comment: I aborted the download at 50 MB.

Comment: @Mark I uploaded to firefox send. Here: https://send.firefox.com/download/ac884328bd79029e/#kWf6cHGAuxmKnBI1MwjHjg Download is 250MB, but expands to 4GB, beware.